# Iterate thru Entry widgets in a Frame

Tags: tkinter

I have several Entry widgets on a frame. Each widget has a textvariable assigned. When all the entries are complete, I want something to happen (like show a calculate button for instance).
How do I iterate through only the Entry widgets to see if their value is not null?

```
self.e1_input = IntVar()
self.e2_input = IntVar()
...
self.e1 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.e1_input, validate='all', ...)
self.e2 = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.e2_input, validate='all', ...)
...
```

There has got to be a way to iterate through the content frame (self) and only pick out the Entry widgets. I can't find a source explaining how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [winfo_children](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_children-method). This returns a list of all widgets that are children of the window.

```
>>> root = Tkinter.Tk()
>>> Tkinter.Entry(root)
>>> root.winfo_children()
[(Tkinter.Entry instance at _____)]
```

Then iterate through the `list` and use `type` to check whether it is a `Entry` widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the frame to a function that will get its children and iterate through if the child is an entry:

```
def get_frame_inputs(frame):
    inputs = [frame.children[x].get() for x in frame.children if 'entry' in x]
    print(inputs)

class MyFrame:
    def __init__(self, master, title, row, col, stk):
        self.lf = LabelFrame(master, text=title)
        self.lf.grid(row=row, column=col, ipadx=5, ipady=5, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=stk)

    def add_entry(self, title, width, row, col, stk):
        Label(self.lf, text=title).grid(padx=5, pady=2, row=row, column=col, sticky=stk)
        self.en = Entry(self.lf, width=width)
        self.en.grid(padx=5, pady=2, row=row, column=col+1)


    def add_button(self, text, row, col, stk):
        Button(self.lf, text=text, command=lambda a=self.lf: get_frame_inputs(a)
        ).grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=stk, padx=5, pady=2)
```