# Treeview select all is slow on large trees

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a control_a method the selects all nodes of a treeview but it's slow on large trees. The method I wrote uses recursion because that is what I think I need to do, am I wrong? Is there a faster way.

The method I'm currently using is below.

```
def control_a(_):
    def walk(children):
        for child in children:
            self.selection_add(child)
            _children = self.get_children(child)
            if _children:
                walk(_children)
    walk(self.get_children())
```

Comment: Your function is fine. Depending on what your children are, there might be a faster way. What are you iterating over? Rows in database? XML file? Have you checked if there is a native iterator? It is very common for Python modules to provide a fast, native way to iterate over something.

Comment: The children are rows in the treeview widget and the data is in the rows.

Comment: Qt? GTK? Tkinter?

Comment: Sorry it's tkinter I'm using. docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview

Comment: i could be wrong but i thought you could just do `treeview.selection_set(treeview.get_children())`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32133549/7919597

Comment: James Kent - That only selects the first level but not it's children.

Comment: @DanielHuckson i've had a look and it doesn't look like there is a better way, all i will say is that you might be able to speed it up by not calling `get_children` twice within your walk function, instead put it into a var and reuse it.

Comment: James Kent -  Thanks I updated the code above to reflect your suggestions. Every little bit of increased speed is welcomed.